# Params hash when no form is posted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

When I do a regular GET, and have nothing in my params, what is the state of the params hash ? Blank ? Nil ? Something else ?

Cause I have a controller that I want to have execute an instruction only if params "has something in it". I tried !params.nil? , !params.blank?

None of those worked, hence I keep entering the if block, and get a nil error...

Help !

Comment: please put some code to clarify :-) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use !params.empty?

Answer (score 0):

When there is no params passed in your get the only thing for sure is that there is a `controller` and an `action` key in your params hash. Now if you don't show me the URL you are GETing I cannot tell you what else is in the params hash, but definitely there must be an `action` and a `controller` key in there. You can always call a `puts(params.inspect)` to see exactly what's going on or use the [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry/) to debug.

Comment: When I write a puts statement in my controller, and don't see anything printed in the console... What is the stdout?

Answer (score 0):

Why not test for something that you are looking for and if it doesn't exist, the hash value will be nil.

```
if params[:something].nil?
  ..
else
  ..
```